# Delphi Firebird

Tags: firebird, restore

In my application, I use Firebird + ZEOSDBO-7.1.4.

To make a backup of the DB, I used ShellApi:

```pascal
FileName := 'C:\MyDATABASE.fbk' ;                      
ShellExecute(0, 'open',                         
   PChar('nbackup.exe'),                            
   PChar('-U SYSDBA -P masterkey -B 0 MyDATABASE.fdb '+ FileName ) ,           
   nil, SW_HIDE ) ;
```

It goes well, but I want to do a restore of the DB.

How to restore the DB using ShellApi please?
Thanks

Comment: [NBackup documentation](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/nbackup.html)

Answer (score 2):

You made a "full backup" (parameter `-B 0`) using the `nbackup` tool. To restore from it you use command line

```
nbackup -R <database> [<backupfile>]
```

So just replace the relevant parameter of your `ShellExecute` call. Note that:

> If the specified database file already exists, the restore fails and you get an error message

Please read more about how to use the `nbackup` tool from the [documentation](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/nbackup-backups.html).

Comment: I tested with the following code but nothing happens yet the syntax is correct:

`ShellExecute(Handle, 'Open', PChar('gbak.exe'),                              
PChar('-c -v -user SYSDBA -password masterkey' + ' ' + 'DATABASE1.fbk ' + ' ' +('DATABASE2.fdb')),                     
nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);                           `

Comment: Yore using `gbak` here while in your question you use `nbackup`! You can't mix them, if you used nbackup to make backup then you must use nbackup to restore from that backup.

Comment: I tried the same code with nbackup.exe but it did not work. I do not get an error message but it does not restore the DB.

Comment: Can you restore the backup from command line? Once you have correct command line, transfer it to your Delphi code. I'd also use full paths to db and backup file instead of just filename.